# Multiplication of a vector and a matrix in c++

Tags: c++

I tried to multiply a vector by a matrix but I can't get it to work because the loop always stops at one line. But with no error code, I've tried different ways to write the code into the resulting vector but it doesn't work. The outputs are to control where the loop stops, it stops after res[i] += (A[i][k] * B[k]);.

This is the specific function to perform the vector & matrix multiplication, if you need all the code let me know.

```
void vector_matrix_multiplication(vector<vector<int>> A,vector<int> B, int col1, int row1, int row2, vector<int>& res) {
int row = row1;
if(row1 < row2)
    row = row2;
for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
    cout << "Loop 1 ";
    cout << i << endl;
        for (int k = 0; k < col1; k++) {
            cout << "Loop 2 " << i << " " << k << endl;
            res[i] += (A[i][k] * B[k]);
            cout << "Loop 2?" << endl;
        }
}
```

The output of the function (with input A = {{2,3},{4,5}} & B = {1,2} is:
Loop 1 0
Loop 2 0 0

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void vectorinput(vector<int>& a, int col){
    cout << "Vector: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < col; i++) {
        int x;
        cin >> x;
        a.push_back(x);
    }

}

void matrixinput(vector<vector<int>>& a, int row, int col){
    cout << "Matrix: " << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
       vector<int> vector;
       for(int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
           int x;
           cin >> x;
           vector.push_back(x);
        }
        a.push_back(vector);
    }
}

int main(){
vector<int> vector;
vector<vector<int>> matrix;  //Matrix is read in separate function

int row1 = 0;                //Number of rows of first matrix
int col1 = 0;                //Number of columns of first matrix
int row2 = 0;                //Number of rows second matrix (redundant in this case)
int col2 = 0;                //Number of columns second matrix

matrixinput(matrix1, row1, col1);
vectorinput(vector2, col2);

    int row = row1;    //Matrix with number of columns "col1", rows "row" - in this case both are 2
    if(row2 > row1)
        row = row2;    //Vector with number of rows "row2" - in this case 2
    vector<int> resvector(row, col1);
    vector_matrix_multiplication(matrix2, vector1, col2, row, col1, resvector);
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        cout << resvector[i] << endl;
    }
return 0;  
}
```

I hope this clarifies the purpose of the program and the function. I tried to cut it down a little because I have a lot of useless code in it. (Plus I struggled to input the code at first, was not quite sure how the code block works - sorry ^^)

Comment: Your source code never prints `Loop 3`, so where did this output come from?

Comment: should be loop 2, my bad; was my 3rd loop initially

Comment: What kind of matrix `input A = {2,3,4,5}` represents? What is row1? What is row2?  What does `if(row1 < row2) row = row2;` do?

Comment: A is a 2x2 Matrix, row 1 is the number of rows for the first matrix & row 2 the number of rows for the vector. If one is larger than the other it chooses the larger one to make sure the program uses the right number of rows (which in this case is the larger one due to the calculation rules of vector and matrix multiplication)

Comment: Did you initialize `res` with the size 2 ? If not, I think that your output is reproduced.

Comment: I've initialized it as vector<int> resvector(row, col1); in my main function

Comment: Could you edit your question and show your main function ? I can not reproduce the above output, https://wandbox.org/permlink/2KNDdUJlVRhjn6bM

Comment: I guess the matrix A should be {{2,3},{4,5}} otherwise there is no sense.

Comment: *A is a 2x2 Matrix* That's probably what you want it to be, but what makes you believe it *is*? There is no connection between your `A` argument and `col1` and `row1`. *If one is larger than the other it chooses the larger one* That's not how vectors work in C++. *due to the calculation rules of vector and matrix multiplication* That's not how multiplication works in linear algebra.

Comment: Yes, A is {{2,3},{4,5}}, changed it, thanks @SHR

Comment: The program changes the rest of the columns to 0 which then have no effect on the multiplication in case one of the both vector/matrix have more columns than the other one (is that not correct?) @n.m.

Comment: Have added the rest of the code to the question @Hiroki

Comment: @IsaacRoberts thx. But I think this code still does not reproduce the above output because  `row1`, `row2`, `col1` and `col2` are all zero through the main function and thus the loop in `vector_matrix_multiplication` does not work. In addition, `matrix1`, `matrix2`, `vector1` and `vector2` are not defined.

Comment: *The program changes the rest of the columns to 0* A matrix *has* rows and columns. They are *inherent* to the matrix. You don't need to keep a (matrix, rows, columns) triple, the matrix itself already contains all the information you need. Same thing about vectors and their size. And when you multiply, number of elements along the relevant dimensions must be the same. Anything else is pure unadulterated madness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are following three bugs in your code:

- Since you use the following ctor of `std::vector`

  > ```
  > explicit vector(size_type count, 
  >                 const T& value = T(),
  >                 const Allocator& alloc = Allocator());
  > ```

  , the second argument of `resvector` must be zero.
- `row1`, `row2`, `col1` and `col2` are all zero through the main function and thus the loop in `vector_matrix_multiplication` does not work.
  We can also reduce these variables to `row` and `col` of the matrix as @n.m. suggests in the comments.
- `matrix1`, `matrix2`, `vector1` and `vector2` are not defined.

In summary, the following minimally fixed version will work fine for you:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> vec;
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mat;

    int row = 2; //Number of rows of matrix
    int col = 2; //Number of columns of matrix

    matrixinput(mat, row, col);
    vectorinput(vec, col);

    std::vector<int> resvector(row, 0);

    // 5th argument is redundant as @n.m. suggested
    vector_matrix_multiplication(mat, vec, col, row, col, resvector);
    for(int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        std::cout << resvector[i] << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you using mathematical libraries for this kind of stuff. The reason is:

- they are already tested by someone else
- they are efficient and optimized to use advanced CPU features
- they are easier to use

I've used two different libraries: [glm](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/index.html) and [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/index.html)

If you want to build your own library for learning purpose I suggest you looking how these libraries are written (they're open source)

Comment: Thanks! Well this is an exercise for my uni and they don't allow libraries which we haven't yet discussed in a lecture